# Create custom WebFaultException

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0, wcf-rest

In a REST WCF Service, is there a way to create a custom WebFaultException?

Right now I am using WebFaultException, but the response doesn't match what the client is expecting. So I'd like to create a custom WebFaultException which will set the HttpStatusCode and add a simple message in the response body (based on my own structure).

Comment: It is _not_ sealed and it _is_ generic. So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Yup, but I cannot change the response format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommed avoiding changing `HtpStatusCode` from inside the custom FaultException. Extending the sevice EndPoint behavior is more robust, because it operates at the `EndpointDispatcher` level, and allows you to inspect and modify `HttpStatusCode` and Message body before sending back the reply, as well as adding custom Message properties in the reply. You will need to add the behaviorExtensions in your service `web.config` file of course.

You can use the following article as a guideline (eventhough it focuses on handling declared fault exceptions for silverlight clients, but the premise is similar)

[Creating and Handling Faults in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844556%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#5)